# How handle Application Error Exception code: 0xc00000fd

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2012

I have an ASP.Net Web API application deployed via IIS. It is in **Windows Authentication enable** mode only because I want to detect Windows users who access the APIs.

For a few days the application will work fine but occasionally it will fail. 
 When the application fails it will present the login prompt several times (minimum 3 times) when requesting the API.  Instead of responding to credentials a "Service Unavailable" message is presented.  At this point the site's application pool stops and an application event log message is created, e.g.:

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.5.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x52157ba0
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.7.2117.0, time stamp: 0x59cf5105
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x00451a8d
Faulting process id: 0xe10
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3a9f540d7b456
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 83502af2-15e8-11e8-80ee-005056b72cd8
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Within my code there is no any debugging error or configuration error.
What will be the problem for that and how handle it?

Answer (score 20):

You are hitting a [`STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx). The problem is in your application code, which you did not post. You are calling something recursively with no exit criteria. Luckily the system has [created a dump for you](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/254649/overview-of-memory-dump-file-options-for-windows), you simply have to [look into it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5zhxt22.aspx) and get your answer.

Comment: Yep. But, Isn't be a problem in windows authentication? It happens after several login prompts.

Comment: @Remus is right. This is a stackoverflow exception. Try capturing a dump by following my blog - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/parvez/2016/08/06/iis-application-pool-crash-and-debug-diag/

Comment: So, what the relationship with providing login prompt several times under widows authentication?

Comment: Thank you Parvez. Debug Diag and your article really helped me today with a difficult situation. I'd upvote more if I could.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ASP.NET Core, take a look at [Debug StackOverflow errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/debug-stackoverflow). There you can also temporarily [enable Log creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/logging-and-diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-7.0) (`stdoutLogEnabled="true"` in web.config) and you'll get the Stack overflow logged with the call stack.

Using the *Debug Diagnostic Tool* in ASP.Net Core would crash the entire Application Pool (Exception code: 0xc0000409 in DbgHost.exe).